# Have child divs in two columns within a parent with left column filled first

Tags: html, parent

I have a js fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/RX2uw/

At the moment this is set up as so:

child 1   child 2
child 3   child 4
child 5   child 6
child 7   child 8

When I want

child 1   child 5
child 2   child 6
child 3   child 7
child 4   child 8

The parent div is of fixed height. I'm just not sure how to get them all into two columns in the right order.

HTML:

```
<div class="err">
    <div class="child">
        Child 1
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        Child 2
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        Child 3
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        Child 4
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        Child 5
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        Child 6
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        Child 7
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        Child 8
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.child {
    width: 48%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: blue;
    border: 2px solid #008888;
    color: white;
    float: left;
}
.err {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
```